# Compound poisson process: Average size of claim will exceed £110

Tags: variance, poisson-process

"An insurance company receives claims at a rate of two per week, the size of a claim in pounds having mean 100 and standard deviation 50. Assuming the compound Poisson process as a model, and using normal approximations, find the probabilities that, in a period of 50 weeks the average size of claim will exceed £110".

As it's a PP, I have

$$Q(t) = \sum_i^{N(t)} Y_i$$

I also have $\mu = 100$ and $\sigma = 50$.

I want to work out $P\left(\frac{Q(t)}{N(t)} > 110 \right) \implies P\{Q(t) - 110N(t) > 0\}$

This tells me I have a new compound PP which can be written as

$$
\tilde{Q(t)} = \sum_i^{N(t)} (Y_i - 110)
$$

Now we want $E[\tilde{Q(t)}]$ and $Var[\tilde{Q(t)}]$

$$
E[\tilde{Q(t)}] = E[Q(t) - 110N(t)] = E[Q(t)] - 110E[N(t)] = \lambda t \mu - 110 \mu = -1000$$

$$
Var[\tilde{Q(t)}] = Var[Q(t)] - 110Var[N(t)] = \lambda t (\sigma^2 + \mu^2) - 110\sigma^2$$

However, this variance is wrong. What is the correct way to work out the variance?

Comment: If this is homework it should have the homework tag.

Comment: It's old homework. That's how I have the answers and know that the variance is wrong.

Comment: OK, just checking.

Comment: This still makes it "homework" within the meaning of "study, review and exercise" as at http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/the-homework-tag-and-homework-policy  (+1 for a well set out question, anyway)

Comment: I note you've written, in the expression for $E[\tilde{Q(t)}]$, $...-110\mu$, which would appear to indicate that you thought $E[N(t)] = \mu$.  By coincidence, $E[N(t)] = \lambda t = 100 = \mu$, but only by coincidence; so you arrived at the right number but by the wrong formula.  Given this, you might want to check the next line to see if you made a similar mistake.